Enumeration of $k$-sparse 0/1-vectors of length $N$
Let $\mathbf{x}$ be a $k$-sparse vector of length $N$ containing $k$ ones. There are $N\choose k$ such vectors and one would need $\log_2 {N\choose k}$ bits to enumerate all of them. Is there an efficient way to go from bits to $\mathbf{x}$? The order in which the ones appear in the vector is unimportant.
One possibility is to enumerate all the vectors and store them in a look-up table, however, the table quickly grows in size. For $N = 100$ and $k = 10$ you need 44 bits but more than 17 trillion entries in the table.
The context for the question is (9) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.00844.

What are the relative sizes of $N$ and $k$, and how much slack do you permit in the bound $\lceil \log_2 \binom Nk \rceil$?

$k$ is up to a few percent of $N$, approximately between $0.001N$ and $0.05N$.  However, $N$ can be large, comparable to the number of variables in a neural network, approximately between $10^4$ and  $10^7$.

The authors of the paper claim that no more bits are needed, so preferably no slack. However, any solution where the number of bits is less than $N$ may be interesting.

I found the answer on Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system.
Let $c_1 < c_2 < \cdots < c_k$ be the indices of the non-zero elements of the $n$th (in lexicographic order) $k$-sparse vector. Then $n = {{c_k}\choose{k}} + \cdots + {{c_2}\choose{2}} + {{c_1}\choose{1}}$ (where $ {a\choose b} = 0$ if $a < b$), so that $n \le \binom{N-1}k + \binom{N-2}{k-1} + \cdots + \binom{N-k}1 = \binom Nk-1$ which can be expressed with $\lfloor \log_2 ({N\choose k}-1) \rfloor + 1$ bits.
To go from $n$ to $c_1, ..., c_k$ you do a greedy search.
First, you find the largest $c_k$ such that ${c_k \choose k} \leq n$. Then, you find the largest $c_{k-1}$ such that ${c_{k-1} \choose {k-1}} \leq n - {c_k \choose k}$, and so on.
